# Down Sides to Using Properties as Opposed to Method Variables

Tags: c#, methods, properties

I am debating the pros and cons of a couple of utility classes I have. The classes have a couple of properties which are set prior to calling the class methods. However, I was wondering if there are any cons to this approach rather than sending a variable along with the method call? There are typically only one or two methods in these classes.

Thank you.

Comment: recommended reading: **[What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)**

Answer (score 3):

If I'm reading the question correctly, you're asking whether to use

```
obj.Foo(bar);
```

or

```
obj.Bar = x;
obj.Foo();
```

Most of the time, the former is better, because it makes it much clearer that bar is required for the `Foo()` operation, it makes it impossible (in a statically typed language) to forget to provide a bar value, and it makes the behavior of `Foo()` easier to reason about when each call only depends on its parameters and not the "state of the world" at the time it was called.